# How to access a structure array from 2 different files?

Tags: c++

How would I go about doing something like this?

header.h

```
 struct myStruct;
 extern myStruct array[];
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
struct myStruct{
int a = 0;
};
myStruct array[5];
array[0].a = 1;
```

file2.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
std::cout << array[0].a;
```

Comment: Passing by reference?

Comment: @Offtkp It looks like it's a global variable so no references needed. I don't understand the question though. Please make a [mre]

Comment: Your `main.cpp` file doesn't have a `main`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you should put `struct` declarations in the header files.

Second, you can't put assignments to arrays or `std::cout` statements just loose in files. I'm assuming you did this for short code and not because you didn't know it needed to be in a function, but I'm pointing it out just in case.

Third, struct declarations require a semicolon

What you would do is have a header file:

header.hpp:

```
#pragma once

struct MyStruct {
    int a = 0;
};

extern MyStruct array[5];
```

The `extern` here means that the data is somewhere else. So let's make the somewhere else.

header.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"

MyStruct array[5];
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"

void someFunction() {
    ...
    array[0].a = 1;
    ...
}
```

file2.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header.hpp"

void someOtherFunction() {
    ...
    std::cout << array[0].a;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I thought we shouldn't be initializing variables for header files?

Comment: @Salty
That just declares the default for the value and there's nothing really wrong with doing that.
If you wanted to, you could add a `MyStruct()` constructor and then in header.cpp do `MyStruct::MyStruct() : a(0) {}` for the same effect, or since the value is 0 and it's an integer, you could just leave it blank, but there's nothing wrong with declaring default values for sruct members.

Comment: @Salty
In short, nothing I'm doing is initializing a variable in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

The size and layout of `myStruct` needs to be known everythere you try to access its contents, so you must either define it inside of the .h file, or only access it using opaque pointers and dedicated functions.

Also, using C arrays in C++ is somewhat outdated. You should use STL containers instead, such as `std::array<T, N>` or `std::vector<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about doing something like this?

You could go about doing something like what you did by doing something like what you did, except fixing the bugs in your attempt. Here is the list of bugs:

- You failed to end the definition of `myStruct` with a semicolon.
- `.c` suffix is conventionally for C source files while you're writing C++. Your compiler will likely be confused unless you provide some unconventional options to the compiler.
- You use `cout` which you forgot to declare. Or did you intend to use `std::cout`? In that case you must include `<iostream>` in order to use it, and use the appropriate namespace.
- In `file2.c`, you use the class `myStruct` in a way that depends on the definition of `myStruct` without providing that definition.
- `array[0].a = 1;` and `cout << array[0].a;` are expression statements. Expression statements may not be in namespace scope, and must be within a block scope. In your program, those expression statements are in the namespace scope which makes the program ill-formed.